# Java Resultset.getInt() not returning properly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I'm making a program that has to alert an user if some threshold has passed for an ammount of money.

I've made a method to check if the user has been alerted already for that threshold so we dont repeat alerts, for that I've setup a MySQL table that fills with 1s and 0s based on whether the alert has been sent already or not.

This is the table:

```
mysql> describe avisos;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CLI            | varchar(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| mes            | int(2)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AvisadoPrimero | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AvisadoSegundo | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AvisadoTercero | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| AvisadoCuarto  | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However when in my program I do a query to check if the alarm was already sent, no matter what, the code will always return 0 (hence stating that the alarm was not sent).

Here you can see the value for the field I'm looking for:

```
mysql> SELECT AvisadoPrimero from avisos where CLI=#########; //(hidden for security reasons)
+----------------+
| AvisadoPrimero |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here is my code that runs within my program:

```
         try {
        Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement avisosQuery = conexion.prepareStatement(avisosString);
        PreparedStatement subtotalesQuery = conexion.prepareStatement(subtotalesString);
        //ResultSet sobrepasados = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT cli FROM subtotales where Precio >=" + umbralInferior + " and Precio <" + umbralSuperior + ";");
        subtotalesQuery.setInt(1, umbralInferior);
        subtotalesQuery.setInt(2, umbralSuperior);
        sobrepasados = subtotalesQuery.executeQuery();
        while (sobrepasados.next()) {
            clis.add(sobrepasados.getString("CLI"));
        }
        if (!clis.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clis.size(); i++) {

                switch (umbralInferior) {
                    case UMBRAL1:
                        avisosQuery.setString(1, "AvisadoPrimero");
                        avisosQuery.setString(2,clis.get(i));
                        resultado = avisosQuery.executeQuery();

                        resultado.first();

                        //System.out.println("Entrando en prueba\n\nConsulta realizada:");
                        //System.out.println(resultado.getInt("CLI"));
                        System.out.println(resultado.getInt(1));
```

So, as you can see given the table with the field set as 1, the last print will always print 0.

Any tips? What am I doing wrong?

==============

Finally, by using the PreparedStatement and fixing the column name, worked out.

(also I believe there was something wrong with some trigger in the MySQL table that was initializing to 0 the field always, but this is unconfirmed)

Here's the final code:

```
try {
        Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement avisosQuery = conexion.prepareStatement(avisosString);
        PreparedStatement subtotalesQuery = conexion.prepareStatement(subtotalesString);
        //ResultSet sobrepasados = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT cli FROM subtotales where Precio >=" + umbralInferior + " and Precio <" + umbralSuperior + ";");
        subtotalesQuery.setInt(1, umbralInferior);
        subtotalesQuery.setInt(2, umbralSuperior);
        sobrepasados = subtotalesQuery.executeQuery();
        while (sobrepasados.next()) {
            clis.add(sobrepasados.getString("CLI"));
        }
        if (!clis.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < clis.size(); i++) {

                switch (umbralInferior) {
                    case UMBRAL1:
                        //avisosQuery.setString(1, "AvisadoPrimero");
                        avisosQuery.setString(1,clis.get(i));
                        resultado = avisosQuery.executeQuery();

                        resultado.first();

                        //System.out.println("Entrando en prueba\n\nConsulta realizada:");
                        //System.out.println(resultado.getInt("CLI"));
                        System.out.println(resultado.getBoolean(1));
```

Thanks all!!

Comment: Have you tried it with rsultado.getInt(1)?

Comment: Add a `System.out.println` statement to print the value of `clis.get(i)` to make sure that you're selecting what you think you are selecting.

Comment: Yes, with the same Luck, returns 0.

Comment: Also, you should use `PreparedStatement` and use parameterized queries (with `?` in them, set parameters on the statement) instead of concatenating the parameters into the SQL string.

Comment: Also done what @Jesper suggests, just didnt paste it here so it will be clearer to read for you

Comment: Maybe it's the wrong datatype Maxint = 2147483647 and your field has a length of 11 digits. You could try it with getLong() or getBigDecimal().

Comment: @Lowb Have you tried to put the cli-field in the resultset and print it out? Maybe theres a problem with your concatenated query (@Jesper PreparedStatement is a good hint) and you are in the wrong record?

Comment: If you tried preparedstatement, edit your question and paste the code.

Comment: @Andreas yes, did print the cli field to make sure I was doing the good query, like this  System.out.println("Entrando en prueba\n\nConsulta realizada: SELECT AvisadoPrimero from avisos where CLI=" + clis.get(i) + ";");

Comment: @Lowb You missunderstood me. I ment to change the statement, so that you could read the CLI from the resultset. like this: resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT CLI as CLI,AvisadoPrimero as AvisadoPrimero from avisos where CLI=" + clis.get(i) + ";"); ... System.out.println(resultado.getString(1));...

Comment: ok i get what you mean now, gonna try it

Comment: @Andreas just tried, and it returns and prints the right CLI (the one which has AvisadoPrimero set to 1)

Comment: Mmmh, it's some time that i used MySql, but i remember we had some problems with older jdbc-drivers. Maybe you could use the latest version. But besides of this and getLong() or getBigDecimal() i'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Modified the code for the use with PreparedStatement and now im getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'AvisadoPrimero', same happens with getLong()
Tried getBoolean("AvisadoPrimero") but returns false
getBigDecimal() returns java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for BigDecimal 'AvisadoPrimero' in column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL prepared statements don't allow parametric column or table names. The code, as it stands now, selects the string `"AvisadoPrimero"` rather than the value of the column. That is, when you write:

```
PreparedStatement avisosQuery = conexion.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT ? FROM avisos WHERE CLI=?");
avisosQuery.setString(1, "AvisadoPrimero");
avisosQuery.setString(2,clis.get(i));
```

the database receives:

```
SELECT "AvisadoPrimero" FROM avisos WHERE CLI=something
```

Then the call to getInt fails because the text `"AvisadoPrimero"` cannot be converted to a number.